# Compute the coefficient of $x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Consider the formal power series
$$F(x) = \sum_{k\ge0}(x+x^2-x^3)^k$$
How can I compute the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(F(x)) ^2$?

I have already rewritten F(x) as
$$F(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} [(x ^n) (2n+3+(-1)^n)/4] $$ if that helps

Comment: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two power series, do you know what is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product $f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: $F(x)$ is a geometric series, right? So. it's $1/(1-x-x^2+x^3)$, which is $1/((1-x)(1-x^2))$. So $F^2$ can be written as $1/((1-x)^2(1-x^2)^2)$. Now it's time for partial fractions.

Comment: ...and then for [differentiating geometric power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550521) ;-)

Comment: Note that $\,(F(x))^2\,$ is the generating function of [OEIS sequence A006918](https://oeis.org/A006918).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552551/prove-the-numbers-are-positive-integers/4552556#4552556) that for $n\ge 0$
$$\frac{2n+3+(-1)^n}{4}=k+1\qquad (\ast)$$

Where $n=2k$ if $n$ is even and $n=2k+1$ if $n$ is odd.

Now when multiplying $F(x)F(x)$, the term containing $x^n$ is given by
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (a_ix^i)(a_{n-i}x^{n-i})$$
So the coefficient of $x^n$
is given by
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (a_i)(a_{n-i})$$

With $a_n=k+1$ as defined in $(\ast)$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\boldsymbol{n}   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\\hline
\boldsymbol{k}   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\\\hline
\boldsymbol{a_n} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4\\\hline
\end{array}$$
From here you take 2 cases, one if $n$ is even and one if $n$ is odd

**Case 1:** $n=2k+1$
\This case is simple to write since because we have even number of coefficients so they basically “aligns” for example if $n=7$, $k=3$ and list of coefficients is
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\boldsymbol{n}   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\\hline
\boldsymbol{k}   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\\\hline
\boldsymbol{a_n} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 4\\\hline
\end{array}$$
so the sum becomes
$$(1)(4)+(1)(4)+(2)(3)+(2)(3)+(3)(2)+(3)(2)+(4)(1)+(4)(1)$$
which can be seen as
$$2[(1)(4)+(2)(3)+(3)(2)+(4)(1)]$$
so, for any $n\ge 3$,
$$\Rightarrow\sum_{i=0}^n (a_i)(a_{n-i})$$
$$=2\sum_{t=1}^{k+1} (t)(k-t+2)$$
Which can be calculated using a simple summation formula

**Case 2:** $n=2k$
\This is a bit more calculated to write since we now have an odd number of coefficients. For example if $n=6$, $k=3$, and the list of coefficients becomes
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\boldsymbol{n}   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
\boldsymbol{k}   & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\\hline
\boldsymbol{a_n} & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
\end{array}$$
so the sum no longer "aligns" and becomes
$$(1)(4)+(1)(3)+(2)(3)+(2)(2)+(3)(2)+(3)(1)+(4)(1)$$
which can be seen as two summations
$$(1)(4)+(2)(3)+(3)(2)+(4)(1)\text{ and } (1)(3)+(2)(2)+(3)(1)$$
So, for any $n\ge 3$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (a_i)(a_{n-i})$$
$$=\sum_{t=1}^{k+1} (t)(k-t+2)+\sum_{t=1}^{k}(t)(k-t+1)$$
Which can also be calculated using a simple summation formula

Hope this helps

Comment: It helps a lot but can you explain more analytically how you got the sums for odd and even n? Did you just found it through the examples?

Comment: I have added a table of how $a_n$ is calculated, is this clearer?

Comment: That helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: You’re more than welcome :) Don’t forget to upvote:)

Comment: Isn't it true that (1)(3)+(1)(3)+(2)(2)+(2)(2)+(3)(1)+(3)(1)= 20? But $$ 2\sum_{i\ge0} [(i) (3-i) ] = 8 $$ (for k=3). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes it should start from $i=1$, fixing so the formula needs to be adapted

Comment: The sum again ends up being 8. Maybe change (k-i) to (k+1-i)?

Comment: Also in case 2 if n=5 then k should be 2,shouldn't it?

Comment: Here you go!, fixed everything, and reordered it to give nicer explanation for examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139878/discussion-between-andromeda-papa-and-sam).